# Match all files exclude multiple directories with glob pattern

Tags: node.js, glob, node.js-fs, minimatch

I'm trying to write a glob to match all files exclude two directories: `app/home` and `node_modules/package1`

```
/test/app/home
/test/app/list
/test/app/Test1
/test/app/Test2
/test/app/Test3
/test/node_modules/package1
/test/a/home
/test/b/package1
```

`**/!(home|package1)` works well to exclude `home` and `package1` [Link](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2F!(home%7Cpackage1)&f=%2Ftest%2Fapp%2Fhome%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2Flist%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2FTest1%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2FTest2%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2FTest3%2C%2Ftest%2Fnode_modules%2Fpackage1%2C%2Ftest%2Fa%2Fhome%2C%2Ftest%2Fb%2Fpackage1)

I want something like `**/!(app/home|node_modules/package1)`, however it doesn't match anything

Answer (score 0):

You can match multiple files by changing your exclusion pattern to only include the section that will be different in your exclusion pattern.

Instead of:

```
**/!(app/home|node_modules/package1)
```

Try:

```
**/app/!(home|node_modules)/package1
```

Comment: it doesn't match any files: [link](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2Fapp%2F!(home%7Cnode_modules)%2Fpackage1&f=%2Ftest%2Fapp%2Fhome%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2Flist%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2FTest1%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2FTest2%2C%2Ftest%2Fapp%2FTest3%2C%2Ftest%2Fnode_modules%2Fpackage1%2C%2Ftest%2Fa%2Fhome%2C%2Ftest%2Fb%2Fpackage1)